# Returning compact user (not mini) with foursquare checkins

Tags: facebook, foursquare

I want to get all of a user's friend's checkins, and be able to find out that friend's facebook id without having to make an additional request. This is only included in compact and complete user objects, not in mini user objects which are returned with checkins.

Looking through the API docs, it appears that there is no way to request specific fields, or modifications to the results. This seems silly and a bit unlikely since that wastes a ton of resources on both sides of the API, so I'm curious if there is a way to do this that hasn't been initially obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately cherry-picking fields you want back in a response isn't supported by the API; you'll have to make the additional request.